# Enabling TLSv1 in postgres12 / openssl1.1.1f

Tags: postgresql, ssl, tls-1.2

After upgrading a server to postgres12 / OpenSSL 1.1.1f (Ubuntu 20.04) I got `tlsv1 alert protocol version` error messages from a client using an old openssl 1.0.1 library supporting only tlsv1.

I thought setting  `ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1'` in **postgresql.conf** should enable the protocol allowing that client to connect. However it does not. I used nmap to check for supported protocols and found only one section with the TLSv1.2 ciphers:

```
➜  ~ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 5432 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-23 22:28 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000064s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
<snip>
```

I used this SE answer [Ubuntu 20.04 - how to set lower SSL security level?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1233456/931458) to change the system default `MinProtocol` setting in **openssl.cnf** to `TLSv1` and postgres picked up this setting (also the openssl1.0.1 client could connect with this setting):

```
➜  ~ sudo service postgresql restart
➜  ~ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 5432 127.0.0.1
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-23 22:31 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000062s latency).

PORT     STATE SERVICE
5432/tcp open  postgresql
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
<snip>
|   TLSv1.1: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
<snip>
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
<snip>
```

For curiosity I changed `ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1.2'` in **postgresql.conf** to see if the postgres server uses the intersection of the two configured ranges and after some debugging help from Laurenz i found that this setting was applied.

My question remained:

How can I configure my system so that postgres will accept `TLSv1` through `TLSv1.2` connections while keeping the openssl default `MinProtocol`setting of `TLSv1.2`?

Comment: I am a bit confused. If you disable OpenSSL connections with a protocol version under TLSv1.2, how should PostgreSQL be able to use TLSv1?

Comment: I thought potgres `ssl_min_protocol_version` would override the openssl `MinProtocol` setting. But instead it seems to me, that the postgres setting has no effect at all. If I set the openssl `MinProtocol` to `TLSv1` and postgres `ssl_min_protocol_version` to `TLSv1.2` postgres still accepts `TLSv1` connections.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I didn't understand that from your question. What do you see in `pg_stat_ssl`? Did you reload after you changed the parameter? Check with `SHOW ssl_min_protocol_version;`.

Comment: `postgres=# show ssl_min_protocol_version; 
FEHLER:  unbekannter Konfigurationsparameter »ssl_min_protocol_version«`

Comment: Then you are not connected to PostgreSQL v12. Perhaps a wrong database.

Comment: Yes. I am sorry, I have been confused by different versions on my system. Now I see, I can limit the range of default protocols from openssl.cnf by specifying a higher version in postgresql.conf. But I can not extend that range to an earlier version. Is that correct?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but PostgreSQL cannot use an older protocol version than OpenSSL accepts. So if you configure OpenSSL to not allow TLSv1, PostgreSQL cannot use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113368/discussion-between-clamp-and-laurenz-albe).

Answer (score 0):

As Laurenz Albe pointed out, it is not possible to configure postgres to use a protocol version older than the `MinProtocol` specified in **openssl.cnf**.

It is however possible to make postgres use its own version of **openssl.cfg**. This way postgres can use `TLSv1` without affecting the system default.

To achieve this I added the following line to the **environment** file in pg's config directory:

```
OPENSSL_CONF = '/etc/postgresql/12/main/openssl.cnf'
```

I then copied */etc/ssl/openssl.cnf* to this directory and made the changes there i.e.:

```
# beginning of openssl.cnf
openssl_conf = default_conf

# end of openssl.cnf
[ default_conf ]

ssl_conf = ssl_sect

[ssl_sect]

system_default = system_default_sect

[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1
CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
```

Now `ssl_min_protocol_version = 'TLSv1'` in *postgresql.conf* works and the rest of the system still uses the openssl default of `TLSv1.2`